# How to implement HSR (Hierarchical state routing) in NS2 in Ubuntu

Tags: ns2

I am new to Network Simulator (NS2). I want to simulate HSR (Hierarchical state routing) over ns2.34 or 2.35. 
**Is there anybody that have HSR Patch?**

Comment: Theoretically? hierarchical state routing should be possible with ns2 by default https://ns2blogger.blogspot.dk/p/protocols-and-models-support-by-ns2-in.html ... **Doc** https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/node379.html ... But the "hierarchical" examples `ns-2.35/tcl/{test/hier-test-1000.tcl, ex/hier-rtg-100.tcl}` don't seem to work. ( ex/hier-rtg-10.tcl is OK.)

Comment: Other 'hierarchical' examples, see `clustering-examples-12.17.tar.gz` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_g0SPnuOMYUuFqkNxnePl-fsmItbRx-U/view?usp=sharing ...

Comment: how about in ns3?

Comment: ns3 : Please ask in the ns3 Forum https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-3-users

Comment: is there any example for HSR simulation in manet?

Comment: ns2 https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+hierarchical+state+routing+manet ... **ns3** https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns3+hierarchical+state+routing+manet